# How do I store data in an array with an asynchronous fetch request over multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, async.js, rest

I'm currently going through different pages to collect objects that meet a certain condition. My code works if I replace the last line with an console.log instead of a returned object. I'm trying to understand why the no object is being returned at the end after everything has been processed.

```
async function getObjects(threshold) {
    let pages
    let objectNames = []
    
    const extractObjects = (json) => {
        for (const object of json.data) {
            if (object.item_count > threshold) objectNames.push(object.titleName);
        }
    }
    
    const getFirstPage = await fetch('https://website.com/api/objects').then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
        pages = json.total_pages
        extractObjects(json)
    });
    
    for (let i=0;i<pages;i++) {
        await fetch(`https://website.com/api/objects?page=${i+1}`).then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
        extractObjects(json)
    });
    }
    return objectNames
    
}
```

Comment: What is objectName? You only have the objectNames array. Also, replace all thens with awaits. Thens are executed on separate event loop functions.

Comment: the for loop does not wait for an asynchronous operation to complete before continuing on to the next iteration use  `for of`

Comment: `then` and `await` both execute in the same event loop - there are some optimizations that `await` is allowed that `then` is not, but they are mostly substitutable for each other.

Comment: @taha wrong! await halts execution, no matter if it is in a loop or not.

Comment: What exactly does "is not being returned" mean?

Answer (score 0):

An `asynchronous function` always returns a Promise no matter what. Even when nothing is returned. In your example there is one return statement   `return objectNames`. Whatever happens within the function. Your function at the end of the day is returning a `Promise Object`.

So where ever you are calling `getObjects`, use `then()` block after it to check the result coming back from your `async` function.

```
getObject().then(data=>console.log(data)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

**Async-Await Demo Example:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/PoGQpzE?editors=0011

Comment: Most likely what's going on - worth noting that in the context of another `async` function that `then` can be turned into another `await` - e. g. `const data = await getObject();`

Comment: Yes Indeed... And that will be a good practice also.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to get it to return something that is not a `Promise Object`? I used a `then()` block, and it returns an empty array.

Comment: Yes, See within your code... You have two awaits.. Within any then() block inside return data and you will have your data :)

Comment: Suppose if after this line: Do a return pages in first await ...                                                                                                                     pages = json.total_pages
return pages;

Comment: @Donnovan: Have a look at this example https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/PoGQpzE?editors=0011

Comment: @Donnovan : By the way none of your API endpoints are returning any data :) Neither this https://website.com/api/objects nor this https://website.com/api/objects?page=1. I tried to hit the link in the browser url.. It revealed no data in both the cases.  Try yourself. There is no data being returned from these end points at all :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather try https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/article_users

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather what I'm trying to accomplish the array being returned not from a `.then()` appended to my function, but rather from the function being called.